# Python - Structuring a file similar to another pickled file

Tags: python, pickle

I have [this pickled file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/j6y34y2vz1c3n7f/batch?dl=1) (29.60 MB), and would like to pickle another file that would be similar to its structure.

I have the following script for unpickling the file:

```
import _pickle as cPickle 

def unpickle(file):
    fo = open(file, 'rb')
    dict = cPickle.load(fo, encoding='latin1')
    fo.close()
    return dict

content = unpickle('batch')
output_file = open('content.txt', 'w')
output_file.write(str(content))
```

What I would like to ask is the following:

**1.** I have two images, one called `image1.jpg` and the other `image2.jpg`, where `image1.jpg` would have the label `1`, and `image2.jpg` would have the label `2`.

What would the pickle file look like based on the file above (if you can kindly demonstrate it)?

**2.** How would I write a Python code that would pickle the data in a structure similar to the file above?

Thanks.

Comment: A Picked file is a binary representation of a python object. You are not supposed to know what the file looks like. What's the use case? PS: your import looks wrong. Just `import cPickle` (for python 2) or `import pickle` (for python 3)

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply. The use case is that I want to read a file and return its name, data, and label, as shown here: names, data, labels =
    cifar_tools.read_data('C:\\Users\\abc\\Desktop\\Testing')

Comment: So you want to look at the *contents* of a pickle output file, and from that determine what the file is, without unpickling it? It makes sense, but I wouldn't bet on it being possible. I don't know though.

Answer (score 1):

It's very simple. Pickle lib function similarly to any other data serialisation lib, such as json, with the extra feature of being able to (de-)serialize native Python objects.

If you have a dict that you would like to be pickled similarly than your example file, simply call `pickle.dump(my_dict)` et voilà, you have the binary data that you can write to a file.

If you are asking how the pickle file is structured, here's how: you have a dict with four keys:

```
>>> pickled_dict.keys()
['data', 'labels', 'batch_label', 'filenames']
```

- 'labels' is a list of 10000 numbers in a 0-9 range .
- 'batch_label' is a string 'training batch 1 of 5'.
- 'filenames' is a list of 10000 strings (image file names).
- 'data' is an array of 10000 arrays, each being of variable size of 8 bit unsigned integers. It is a numpy.ndarray object (numpy is a python lib for manipulating binary/numeric data matrices), which i suppose should indicate you how the "images" were loaded in the first place - maybe simply loaded in binary mode and wrote char by char into an array, but I can only guess here.

Structure your own batch by mocking this dict.
If you need to know how i got this data, that's simply by using your depickle code and calling `__class__`, `keys()`, and `len()` on the de-pickled object rather than writing it back to a file (which i suppose, failed on the data part).

Hope this helped.